# Xen - install fully paravirtualized Ubuntu - no virtual kernel in bootloader

Tags: 12.04, kernel, virtualization, xen

I followed this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen
I managed to get 99% the way through it, but it appears the xen-netboot image doesnt install a virtual kernel (it says 'generic' at the end instead of virtual in grub menu) as shown here:
[image: http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/1/1605372042-orig.png]

Here is my config:

```
name = 'client1-ubuntu-32'
memory = 512
disk = ['phy:/dev/ubu-32/xen-lvm,xvda,w']
vif = [' ']

# Comment this out if uncommenting the next section (installing)
#bootloader="/usr/bin/pygrub"

# This section is for installing ubuntu
kernel = "/var/lib/xen/images/ubuntu-netboot/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/var/lib/xen/images/ubuntu-netboot/initrd.gz"
extra = "debian-installer/exit/always_halt=true -- console=hvc0"
```

I used the initrd and vmlinuz from the answer on [this serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/404201/ubuntu-12-04-netinstall-url-xen-host): http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/xen/

To run the paravirtualized guest I need to run the 'virtual' kernel I believe. Do I have to manually copy that to the domU somehow (I have it in my dom0's /boot) or is there a way for the vm to install with it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the user can use 'manual package selection' at the apt/task menu in order to remove the generic kernels and install the virtual one instead.

You also have to ensure that you change the default partitioning from using ext4 to using ext3 for this to work. I don't know if it's a pygrub specific issue or not.

This manual package selection is pain. Worth looking into a way to use the minimal virtual install mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57336/minimal-system-or-minimal-virtual-machine-on-install):