# How to install Ubuntu 14.04 command-line system?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I want to install [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) version of Ubuntu 14.04 on my system, but I could not find an Alternate CD for 14.04 anywhere.

- [Ubuntu install command-line only?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455510/ubuntu-install-command-line-only) - This is Ubuntu Server, I'm looking for a plain version (if any such thing exists)
- [Minimal system or minimal virtual machine on install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57336/minimal-system-or-minimal-virtual-machine-on-install) - Both the versions install server kernel. I'm not aware of what exactly it is, but I don't want any server stuff on my system.

I tried using the [Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), but it stops midway asking for an internet connection. I do not have an internet connection on my machine.

The first link in this question says

> Note: the Server Install CD provides a simple command line system, but it is not the same as "install a command-line system"

I want the `install a command-line system` installer for 14.04.

The Minimal CD page says

> You can also select "Manual package selection" which will take you to aptitude. You may also select nothing and just continue to finish the installation. If you selected nothing, upon reboot you will arrive at a cli prompt; from here you can fully customize your new system.

**This** is what I want. But as mentioned, I don't have an internet connection on that machine, and the Minimal CD doesn't seem to work without it.

Comment: It seems the last alternate cd iso was for [12.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.5/) , on [14.04 downloads](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.4/) i don't see an alternate link

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Well, 12.04 LTS still  has 2 more years of support, so if you can live with that, i will install it and update it.
If not, you can install alternate 12.04 and try to do a `dist-upgrade` to the next LTS which is 14.04 or 16.04, i you do it next month. But maybe that upgrade won't be so minimal, so it's a matter of trying and testing.